# Making Vuetify (3) select dropdowns stand out against card/dialog surfaces

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have a VDialog containing a VCard which in turn contains a VSelect. When I open the VSelect, it is hard to see the drop-down list of options as it has the same color as the VCard. Both seem to have `background: rgb(var(--v-theme-surface));` The only thing making the dropdown stand out is a shadow, but in a dark-theme, you can barely see it.

[image: Example of a drop-down not standing out]

What is the recommended way to change the background of a VSelect (or VMenu, VCombobox) if it is inside a VDialog or VCard?

I know Vuetify 3 has a way to change global config (including nested options, like a VSelect inside a VCard) but I could not get that to work.

I also tried with CSS variables, changing the value of the `--v-theme-surface` CSS property, but it looks like the dropdown is moved outside of the parent container and put close to the html `<body>`, so I can't target it.

Is there a way to 'send in' a CSS class into the child drop down menu so I can target it that way?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to change styles of nested components through Vuetify directly, but using the [`:menu-props`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-menu-props) property, you can pass a configuration object to the underlying `v-menu` component. The content of the [`:content-class`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-content-class) property will be set as class on the overlay content node:

```html
<v-select
  ...
  :menu-props="{
    contentClass: 'lighter-surface',
  }"
>
```

With this, you can now define a CSS rule to adjust the background color variable:

```css
.lighter-surface > .v-theme--dark{
  --v-theme-surface: var(--v-theme-on-surface-variant); /* or something like 55,55,55; */
}
```

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify({theme: {defaultTheme: 'dark'}})
const app = {}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
.lighter-surface > .v-theme--dark{
  --v-theme-surface: var(--v-theme-on-surface-variant);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-card class="ma-4">
        <v-card-title>Selection Card</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-select
            :items="['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3']"
            label="Select"
            :menu-props="{
              contentClass: 'lighter-surface',
            }"
          ></v-select>
          <div style="height: 200px;">
          </div>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to change global styles, you can try to attach the `v-menu` to the `v-card`, using the [`:attach`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-attach) property, then you could work with local styles. Not sure if it's worth it though.

---

Or you can solve it by adding your own theme:

```js
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'dark',
    themes: {
      darkOnSurface: { // <--- name of the theme
        dark: true, // <--- extend dark theme
        colors: {
          surface: 'blue', // <--- override color variant from dark theme
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

And then set that theme in the `v-menu`:

```html
<v-select
  ...
  :menu-props="{
    theme: 'darkOnSurface',
  }"
></v-select>
```

The advantage is that you can use it on all Vuetify components.

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue;
const {
  createVuetify
} = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'dark',
    themes: {
      darkOnSurface: {
        dark: true,
        colors: {
          surface: 'blue',
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
const app = {}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-card class="ma-4">
        <v-card-title>Selection Card</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-select
            :items="['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3']"
            label="Select"
            :menu-props="{
              theme: 'darkOnSurface',
            }"
          ></v-select>
          <div style="height: 200px;">
          </div>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the answer. I've marked it as the correct one, and I will also add another bigger comment with some more thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that! I did some testing and your three methods work great. Here is my thoughts on them.

First, the template:

```html
<v-card id="my-card" style="padding: 1rem; height: 17rem;">
    <v-select label="By Props" :menu-props="{contentClass: 'lighter-surface' }" />
    <v-select label="By Theme" theme="onSurface" />
    <v-select label="By Attach" :menu-props="{attach: '#my-card' }" />
</v-card>
```

The CSS:

```css
// For the 'By Props' method
.lighter-surface [class*=' v-theme--'] {
  --v-theme-surface: var(--v-theme-inner-surface);
  --v-theme-on-surface: var(--v-theme-on-inner-surface);
}
// For the 'By Attach' method
.v-card [class*=' v-theme--'] {
  --v-theme-surface: var(--v-theme-inner-surface);
  --v-theme-on-surface: var(--v-theme-on-inner-surface);
}
```

Vuetify.ts

```js
const defaultDark: ThemeDefinition = {
  dark: true,
  colors: {
    background: '#1D1716',
    surface: '#322929',
    'inner-surface': '#BDBDBD', // For the By Props & Attach method
    primary: '#793C86',
  },
}
const onSurface: ThemeDefinition = {
  dark: true,
  colors: { surface: '#BDBDBD' }, // For the By Theme method
}
createVuetify({
    theme: {
      defaultTheme: 'defaultDark',
      themes: { defaultDark, onSurface },
    },
  })
```

Personally, I prefer the 'By Props' method.

The 'By Attach' method causes functional changes in how e.g. the drop downs are cut off if they overflow their container.

The 'By Theme' method requires that there are always two maintained themes. I prefer  for each theme to be comprise all the colors used throughout the entire application.

It is just a shame that there is no way to automatically detect that a VMenu is used inside a VCard without having to explicitly mark it as such using the menu props. But hey, this works pretty great!